# deserializing into dynamic all the way?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using json.net and loving it. However, when I deserialize to dynamic, I don't get strings, integers, etc. at the bottom, I get JValue objects, e.g.

```
  string json = "[{'x':'1', 'y':'1'}, {'x': '2', 'y': '2'}]";
  dynamic[] rg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic[]>(json);
  //var x2 = rg.First(pt => pt.x.Equals("2"));// JValue has no Equals method
  var x2 = rg.First(pt => pt.x.ToString().Equals("2")); // have to convert to string
  Console.WriteLine(x2);
```

If x were converted to a .NET string as part of the conversion, then I'd have an Equals method. Instead, I have to call ToString on the underlying JValue to get the Equals method. Is there a way to configure the json.net JsonConvert to convert all the way down instead of using JValue objects? I don't see anything obvious in JsonSerializerSettings. Thanks!

Comment: Could you just deserialize to a strongly typed class? Or do you not know the structure?

Comment: you're not using the correct json format validate your json here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I'm using dynamic because I'm dealing with a lot of types and would prefer not to indulge needless ceremony.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `==` operator?  It seems to give the same result without the "needless ceremony".

```
var x2 = rg.First(pt => pt.x == "2");
```

Comment: Because that's only one example of the problem. Another example is when calling a function that requires a string. Or, if the underlying data type is an integer and the function requires an integer, etc.